# Undefined default namespaces in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, namespaces

I'm developing an app in Laravel 5.1. And for some reason there's loads of default namespace paths that are red (using PHPStorm 10). They are marked as "undefined namespace"

For example, when I make a model with artisan it ends up with this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Form extends Model
{
    //
}
```

And **Eloquent** is red. So I can't use the model.

Same goes in app/config/app.php

```
Where Illuminate\Support\Facades\
```

where **Facades** is red.

These are tons of namespace errors like this (under the *Illuminate* root ). Any idea with it might be? See below...

[image]

Comment: have you tried updating your composer ??

Comment: @Drudge Yes. Just did. Smae problem...

Comment: Any error on the browser ??

Comment: check psr-4 autoloading in `composer.json`

Comment: what do you mean with "check psr-4 autoloading in composer.json"?

Answer (score 7):

It's a problem of PHPSTORM.
For those who have this problem, I resolve it by :
- close phpstorm
- remove the project folder .idea
- create a new project with existing files.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

In PhpStorm :

1. Delete the .idea folder from your project,
2. File => Invalidate Caches / Restart,
3. Restart PhpStorm.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

Open setting-> (setting path in image)
check "Synchronize IDE settings with composer.json"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When it happens to me, I place my cursor before `use` and press enter.

Sometimes it fixes that.